# When are array names constants or pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

In a document by Nick Parlante, it says, Array names are constant i.e array base address behaves like a const pointer.

e.g

```
{
    int array[100], i;
    array = NULL; //cannot change base address
    array = &i; // not possible
}
```

But at the same time why is this valid:

```
void foo(int arrayparm[]){

    arrayparm = NULL; // says it changes the local pointer
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays decay into pointers in functions. The array name is a `non-modifable lvalue`. What this means is that, you can do this:

```
int x=10,y=20;
int *p = &x;  // <---- p Now points to x
p = &y; // <---- p Now points to y
```

But **not** this:

```
int arr[10], x=10;
arr = &x; // <-----  Error - Array name is a non-modifiable lvalue.
```

Since arrays decay immediately into pointers, an array is never actually passed to a function.  As a convenience, any parameter declarations which "look like" arrays, e.g.

```
f(a)
char a[];
```

are treated by the compiler as if they were pointers, since that is what the function will receive if an array is passed:

```
f(a)
char *a;
```

This conversion holds only within function formal parameter declarations, nowhere else.  If this conversion bothers you, avoid it; many people have concluded that the confusion it causes outweighs the small advantage of having the declaration "look like" the call and/or the uses within the function.

> References: K&R I Sec. 5.3 p. 95, Sec. A10.1 p. 205; K&R II Sec. 5.3 p. 100, Sec. A8.6.3 p. 218, Sec. A10.1 p. 226;

Answer (score 3):

Function parameter declarations are different then formal declaration is C, in function declaration:

```
void foo(int arrayparm[])
             ^^^^^^^^^ is pointer not array
```

`arrayparm` is pointer but not array its type is `int*`. This is equivalent to:

```
void foo(int *arrayparm)
```

In function `foo` you can modify `arrayparm`.

Whereas in formal declaration(in side function) e.g.

```
int array[100];
```

`array` is not a pointer but it is a constant, It is type is `char[100]` and it is not modifiable lvalue.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for a prompt reply.

Comment: @learning to observe difference apply sizeof operator with each.

Answer (score 1):

When array names are passed as function argument, it "decays" to a pointer. So you can treat it like a normal pointer.

Reference: [**C FAQ** what is meant by the ``equivalence of pointers and arrays'' in C?](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html)

Answer (score 0):

Array types are not assignable in C. It was just a design decision. (It is possible to make assignment of array types copy one array over another, like assignment of structs. They just chose not to do this.)

The C99 standard, 6.5.16 paragraph 2:

> An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left
>   operand.

C99 standard, 6.3.2.1 paragraph 1:

> ... A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that does not have array type,
>   ...

Plus, even if array types were assignable, `NULL` is not a value of type `int[100]`.